# Convert vector of numbers into factors without using if statement

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a vector of numbers that looks like this.

```
> head(test,7)
c(1, 0.68, 0.95, 0.93, 0.33, 0.49, 0.8)
```

I want to create a second vector that places these numbers into categories. So the end result would look like this:

```
>test
Value    Bin
1        >0.9
0.68     0.6-0.9
0.95     >0.9
0.93     >0.9
0.33     <0.5
0.49     <0.5
0.8      0.6-0.9
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can check `?cut`

Comment: what should be the result if `Value` is 0.55?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
>test$Vector.Of.Numbers
1, 0.68, 0.95, 0.93, 0.33, 0.49, 0.8

test$cut <-  cut(test$Vector.Of.Numbers, breaks = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9),
+     labels = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"))
```